# Match a quotation mark " with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to match the following string with regex:

```
texthere("othertext")
```

There might be some whitespaces in before and after the string.

What I tried to do was this (`s` is a `String`):

```
s.matches("\\s*\\w*(\"\\w*\")\\s*");
```

However, this doesn't work. Then I tried several things, until I found out that the following does work:

```
s.matches("\\s*\\w*(.*\\w*.*)\\s*");
```

This would mean that the `\"` part is not recognised as `"`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to escape the `()`.

```
s.matches("\\s*\\w*\\(\"\\w*\"\\)\\s*");
```

Un-escaped, they were acting as a capturing group.

Comment: @Creator13 What do you mean by _doesn't work_? It returns `true`.

Comment: It returns `false` for me.

Comment: @Creator13: you probably need to check your code or your test string. Don't forget that the pattern with `matches` method must describe the entire string, not only a part (otherwise use the `find` method).

Comment: It return false for me `System.out.println(" hi this is my texthere(\"entry\") string".matches("\\s*\\w*\\(\"\\w*\"\\)\\s*"));`

Comment: @Braj That's because that string does not match that pattern. The string in my answer and in the question does.

Comment: Got it it means it check for complete string not for substring.

Comment: @Braj That and the fact that the string in your example here has `word-whitespace-word-whitespace-etc` while the regex has simply `whitespace-word` before the `()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried your site, and there it returns `true`. This means there might be something wrong with the regex or the string to check.

Comment: @Creator13 Yes, check your `String` to see if it is actually what you posted. Ideally, you should post a reproducible example in your question. Alternatively, express what you want to achieve with the regex and `matches`.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. The text inside the quotation marks is meant to be a string and contained whitespaces. I removed them and it worked. Thank you, for solving my first problem, I would not have though of the backslash before the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Here escape character `\` is used escape the character that is already reserved for regex pattern

for example

```
. * ? + ( ) [ ] $ ^ { }
```

Sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\(\"\\s*\\w*\\s*\"\\))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("texthere(\"entry\")");
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("found");
}
```

Comment: That is not the problem I'm having. My string is exactly as written above (only the text might be different).

Comment: It means only string inside the double quotes will be different.

Comment: You're doing something different than op. You should explain that.

Comment: I am thinking that this string is part of another string.

Comment: Then try with my updated code after removing `texthere` from the regex.